# How to put smargwt widget to gwt FlexTable?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm new in Smartgwt, my application is purely designed in GWT and it is decided at some stage that SmartGWT widgets should be used for the functionality, 
How can I put Smartgwt widget like `SelectItem` into a GWT `FlexTable`?

Comment: If I were you I would not mix the two sort of widgets... Either you stay with Gwt or Smartgwt... If you encounter weird behavior you will nver know why....

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add any `FormItem` (i.e. any widget that extends `FormItem` such as `SelectItem`), to any widget but to `DynamicForm`. Please refer to http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/FormItem.html
& http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/DynamicForm.html.

Apart from this, you should also consider what Alain has commented. You should not mix SmartGWT widgets with any of those of GWT or of any other technologies. Please refer to http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8159#aMix